# Can pre-paid Cards work on Realms PC Edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

Recently I started a free trial for Minecraft Realms on the PC edition, but now I've noticed that I have only 6 days left, so I'd like to pay for it. However, I've seen Minecraft pre-paid cards in the store, and I was wondering if I could cash them out to get a longer subscription for realms?

I've not had much look searching on the internet, and so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to this Stack Exchange community!

I'd just like to tell you that when asking a question, try to refrain from using capital letters to emphasize a point, also any potential answerers would know that you're using the PC edition of Minecraft due to the tags that you applied to the question.

Comment: sure, lol i'm new!

Answer (score 1):

**No. Prepaid cards are only for buying Minecraft, in the form of the game.**

Mojang's [page for pre-paid cards](https://minecraft.net/en/prepaid/) says that:

> Minecraft for PC/Mac can be bought via pre-paid cards found in physical stores.

This means that pre-paid cards can be redeemed for buying the actual game. If you want to buy Realms, just go to the [Realms page for PC/Mac](https://minecraft.net/en/realms/pc/) and choose a plan.

Answer (score -1):

There are prepaid Realms cards. Just buy one and follow the dots.